# Efficient way to cache WSDL responses

Tags: java, xml, database, caching, wsdl

My Java-based web application is interacting with a remote WSDL webservice.

I construct a service-specific WSDL request. I issue this WSDL request with an HTTP client, and get back a WSDL response.

As it is acceptable for my circumstances, to optimize performance and bandwith usage, I would like to cache the WSDL response so that the next time I am issuing the same request, my web application can directly load the response from a persisting database.

With `JAXB.marshal` and `JAXB.unmarshal` I can get a response's representation in both serialized XML format and "Java object representation". So I had the idea of setting up a database that persists the marshalled XML representation. But the XML file representation of a typical response can easily be 200 kilobytes large in my case. As we know with XML files, this size is to a good part related to XML's verbosity and can probably reduced by an great amount to both optimize database capacity usage and database read-write speed.

Is there an efficient way of caching and persisting WSDL responses? That is, I'm looking for a good way to implement a map for a function  `f(someWSDLRequest) -> someWSDLResponse`

Comment: A WSDL request? You mean a SOAP request/response, right?

Comment: Yep, it's a SOAP request/response with a backing WSDL

Comment: How can you know the cache is dirty?

Comment: @RosdiKasim Can you elaborate on your question?

Answer (score 2):

To cache you need a key and a value. In this case obviously the value is the response from the SOAP service.

For the key, why not try either concatenating the parameters into a string (I've seen this done many times before) or doing an MD5 hash on the request. It makes the cache key small and simple and it will always be the same if the request is the same.

When a request comes in that you have a response for in cache, serve it.

If it doesn't exist, get it from the database, put it in cache and then serve it.

If the underlying object changes (the cached response), go invalidate the cache, or just put an expiration time on it and let it happen with time.

Comment: Thanks, these are already good ideas and considerations! Regarding the key-as-string generation: The key should probably best be canonicalized (i.e. there shall be a total order on the request parameters) to reduce unnecessary duplicate entries. For instance both `(someValueForParameterA, someValueForParameterB)` and  `(someValueForParameterB, someValueForParameterA)` shall have the same key string representation. ... Regarding the SOAP/XML response: To efficiently persist it, maybe a [native XML database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database#Native_XML_databases) would be useful...?

Comment: Yes for the key generation, I would always compose it from left to right - and you're using the parameter values, not the parameter names. To persist the responses, use something like Memcached or Couchbase or Redis.